# How to add a custom button on the ActiveAdmin show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Here's where I'd like to add a new button:

[image]

I'd like to add a new button on the upper right, pointing to a custom URL based on some properties in the user the page is referring to.

I couldn't find the right options [here](https://activeadmin.info/6-show-pages.html).

Answer (score 18):

They call them [`action items`](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#action-items):

```
action_item :import_demo, only: :show do
  link_to 'Import Demo', '#'
end
```